# Where is the best place to put my ChangeNotifierProvider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-change-notifier-provider

I use ChangeNotifierProvider.

The consumer who will use this ChangeNotifierProvider exists only in one widget, not across multiple widgets.

So I want to register ChangeNotifierProvider only for that widget and use it as a consumer.
At this time, inefficiency occurs

(build first "blank screen" -> information load by calling function in consumer(after build is done by using delayed function) -> rebuild).

when i tried to load information by call a function in my viewModel(consumer) in build, it makes error because  notifyListeners() function is called and it try to rebuild while build is not done. So I had no choice but to first build a blank screen and then call a function to initialize the information.

So, I try to register ChangeNotifierProvider at the top, but since the top is login (the top of all apps), this registration is not inefficiency too.
documentation says:(You don’t want to place ChangeNotifierProvider higher than necessary (because you don’t want to pollute the scope))!

I'm wondering if I can do it.
What choice should I make?

1. Register ChangeNotifierProvider in the corresponding widget and use it as a consumer.
2. Register ChangeNotifierProvider at the top (login widget) and use it by subscribing to the necessary widgets as a consumer.
3. Use another method

Comment: Might be time to migrate to Riverpod.  Remi (the author of the Provider package) suggests that new projects might want to start with his RiverPod instead.  Provider is in maintenance mode, while RiverPod continues to add new cool features constantly.

Answer (score 0):

you should add provider in the main.dart file, if there are multiple providers then you can use MultiProvider for that